# Dims activity except one bright view

Tags: android, android-activity, android-view

I am trying to do a guide for my app. I tries to dim the activity and leaves one clickable bright view (like games and Android itself when its runs first time).

But I don't know where to start to implement that.
Any idea or source-code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your help/intro screen will be an Activity on its own. Therefore:

- Create the Activity
- Let the Layout fill the screen with `fill_parent` in both directions
- Set the background to be 50% transparent with `android:background="#80000000"`.

The rest is up to what you want to show on the bright part of your screen.

Comment: Yea, but if I want that all the activity will be dim, except one button? I dont want to implement all mt buttons twice...

Comment: In this yase, you would need to overlay the layout of each Activity in your App with a number of layouts - one for each view you want to highlight - wrapped by a FrameLayout. I dont think that this will be easier nor less code. Also you would mess up your app with the helper functions.